# Call a function that is in another js file

Tags: javascript

I removed my JS code in separate file and now I want to call it and execute it in the one that it was before. My new file name is blockedComponents.js. I added it in BundleConfig and I am trying to call it methods like this:

```
      function getBlockedComponentsMethods()
      {
             BlockedComponents.pageChangedHandler();
      }
```

My function in the new file is called

```
     function BlockedComponents();
```

Should I require it somehow , because now I have error that pageChangedHandler is not defined?

Comment: What is "BundleConfig"? What bundler are you using?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Does `BlockedComponents` function returns `pageChangedHandler` function? What does `BlockedComponents` code looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't get what are you trying to do here, but in general :

If you would like to call a **static method** like this :

```
BlockedComponents.pageChangedHandler();
```

You should do something like the following :

```
function BlockedComponents() {
//Code here ...
}

BlockedComponents.pageChangedHandler = function() {
//Code here ...
};
```